# Elevator situations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, acceleration

What happens to my weight when I'm in an elevator that's,

**a. stationary**

**b. moving with a constant velocity**

**c. moving upwards with an acceleration *a* where *a*<*g***

**d. moving upwards with an acceleration *a* where *a*=*g***

**e. moving upwards with an acceleration *a* where *a*>*g***

**f. moving downwards with an acceleration *a* where *a*<*g***

**g. moving downwards in freefall**

**c. moving downwards with an acceleration *a* where *a*>*g***

I know that these are basic questions. But I couldn't find a proper explanation of any of these anywhere! Actually I know what I'm gonna weigh in each of the situations(e.g. in **a** I'd weigh m(g + a)) , But I just can't understand why I'm gonna weigh that. I think my understanding of **"weight"** isn't that clear yet aka how we weigh, Is it the normal force...etc. So it'd also be very helpful if someone cleared that up, too. Also I *think* these are the only elevator situations but if there are more please explain those too if you can. And also( yeah yeah I'm a noob) please explain the ***'point of reference'*** thing in these situations (if you can)

Comment: Draw the free body diagrams and solve for the normal force. The apparent weight will be your normal force. Obviously, your 'true weight' is gonna stay the same.

Comment: It would be useful if you showed your work to clarify where you are stuck. I think you probably already know the answer for the 'warm up' part (a), where the elevator isn't accelerating at all and might as well not even be there. What is the first one where you get stuck? Are you stuck because you find multiple answers possible (if so, which ones?), or because you can't think of any answers? If the latter, try taking a default "null hypothesis" that your apparent weight is $mg$. Can you prove or disprove that guess in each case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just handle case (c), which should hopefully illustrate how to handle the other cases.

You have a weight $W = mg$, but you are accelerating upwards at some acceleration $a < g$. From Newton's 2nd law, the net force on you is $F = ma$. This force is the sum of two forces - the one exerted on you by the elevator floor, and the one due to gravity. In other words,

$$F_{\text{elevator}} - W = ma$$

Where the negative sign is because the two forces are in opposite directions.

The weight you feel is $F_{\text{elevator}}$. This is because your weight you feel is always equal to the normal force you feel, regardless of what the source of that force is. Put another way, your weight acts on whatever is supporting you (such as a chair). By Newtons 3rd law the chair also exerts that same force on you, and this is the force you experience, since it acts *on* you (give this a think if it's not clear). It's a simple matter now to see that

$$F_{\text{elevator}} = mg + ma$$

So your weight increases. This shouldn't be surprising if you've been in an elevator before - you feel heavier when you are accelerating upwards, and lighter if you are decelerating.

Comment: I just now realized would you actually accelerate upwards if a<g? Doesn't a have to be greater than g for the elevator to  accelerate upwards?

Comment: @AbdullahChowdhuryRafi you can accelerate upwards at any acceleration. If you accelerate upwards at a = g, then the weight you feel is exactly twice your "sitting" weight.